# Avoid chapter pagebreak in twocolumn document

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, two-column, titlesec

It took me a while to locate the error, but here's a MWE.
I am using my own class, provided below:

```
 \documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twocolumn]{MWEclass}
 \usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text
 \definecolor{pt_Blau_04}{RGB}{20,20,20}

   \begin{document}
    \makeatletter 
         \renewcommand\chapter{\global\@topnum\z@
                 \@afterindentfalse
                 \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
    \def\@topnewpage[#1]{#1}
 \makeatother

 \input{MWEchapter}
 \chapter{Something}
 \lipsum[7-10]
 %\input{MWEchapter2}
 %\input{MWEchapter3}
  \end{document}
```

and the class:

```
 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
 \ProvidesClass{MWEclass}[17/06/2013, v1.0]

 \AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
 \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
 \ProcessOptions*
 \LoadClass{report}
 \RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}


 \RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
 \newlength\mylena
 \newlength\mylenb
 \setlength\mylena{1.3cm}
 \setlength\mylenb{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\mylena\relax}

 \newcommand\PlaceNumber[1]{%
   \makebox[\mylena][l]{#1}}

 \titleformat{\chapter}
  {\color{pt_Blau_04}\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\PlaceNumber{\thechapter}\parbox[t]{\mylenb}{\raggedright#1}}

 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
```

If i want to avoid the pagebreak for every new chapter (The chapters MWEchapter are just lipsum text) it works up to including TWO chapters, if I want to include more, theres an error message about horizontal mode and the titlesec package..

Comment: If you don't want chapters to start a new page, why do you base your document class on `book`, rather than `report`?

Comment: the same happens if i use report.. i guess its because of the twocolumn thing

Comment: I just checked with a `twocolumn` `book` together with your code snippet, and it does *not* break pages at new chapters. So please provide a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that let us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done, the problem is including more than two chapters.. but how can i fix that..

Comment: I tried the updated MWE, and again, no page breaks. Please *test* your MWE before posting it.

Comment: I tested it :-) No page breaks, BUT try to uncomment the two more input{MWEchapter2} and input{MWEchapter3}, it doesnt work then!

Comment: Hm, no page breaks for me. I put `\chapter{...}\lipsum[7-10]` in the three `MWEchapter.tex` files, and get three chapters on two pages.

Comment: the problem with my MWE was that i had a space between MWEchapter and '2' (\input{MWEchapter 2}) and it works now.. my main document (where I have no spaces in chapter names at all) still doesnt work and its driving me crazy.

It says: ! Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode. which is the same thing it said in my MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stems from the fact that your redefinition of `\chapter` does not make sure that a paragraph is ended when the chapter title is about to be typeset. So something like

```
Text\chapter{Foo}
```

triggers the error.

Since you are using `titlesec` anyway, I would recommend to remove the hacky redefinition of `\chapter`, and use the interface of `titlesec` to make chapters not start a new page. This can be achieved by setting the class of `\chapters` from `top` to `straight`. `MWEclass.cls` then looks like this (see the last line):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
 \ProvidesClass{MWEclass}[17/06/2013, v1.0]

 \AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
 \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
 \ProcessOptions*
 \LoadClass{report}
 \RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

 \RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
 \newlength\mylena
 \newlength\mylenb
 \setlength\mylena{1.3cm}
 \setlength\mylenb{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\mylena\relax}

 \newcommand\PlaceNumber[1]{%
   \makebox[\mylena][l]{#1}}

 \titleformat{\chapter}
  {\color{pt_Blau_04}\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\PlaceNumber{\thechapter}\parbox[t]{\mylenb}{\raggedright#1}}

 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}%% added
```

and the redefinition of `\chapter` in your main file can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, only the cleardoublepage needs to be reset, if you hold it in memory, it can be restored.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
Bla
\chapter{Two}
Bla Bla

%Reset
\makeatletter
    \let\cleardoublepage@old\cleardoublepage
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
\makeatother

\chapter{Three}
Bla Bla Bla

%Restore
\makeatletter
    \let\cleardoublepage\cleardoublepage@old
\makeatother

\chapter{Four}
Bla Bla Bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: That doesnt work in twocolumn documents. it says "Float(s) lost"

Comment: I don't know in that case.